# CE-CE-Class AB Amp Design Help

Tags: circuit-design, power-amplifier

[image: CE-CE-CLASS AB Multi-Stage Amp]

[image: Class AB Gain]

I'm tasked to design an audio amplifier with a class AB amp as the last stage.
For the first two stages, CE-CE, the gain amounts to 100+. But when connected to the driver stage, the output suddenly drops drastically to uV.

We haven't been taught AB Amps so the schematic I have is just taken from other internet sites. Can someone explain why the gain gets cut?

Comment: Look for another schematic on the "internet sites" this one has lots of problems.

Comment: Let's see. You've been tasked to design a class-AB, haven't been taught them, and in any case also don't appear to have been taught anything about global negative feedback, VAS design, or bootstrapping, either. Does this sound like a rational "tasking" to you? Well, at least you've managed to convert a \$40\:\textrm{mV}_\textrm{PP}\$ signal into a \$900\:\mu\textrm{V}_\textrm{PP}\$ signal using a bunch of BJTs. The internet must be good for something. You have this in simulation, by the way. Why haven't you been able to track down the problem regarding loss of gain?

Comment: I'll add a clue about a glaring hole among others, though. What is \$R_9\$ supposed to do for you and how is it supposed to be arranged in order for it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The main error is that R6 (the load) should not go to ground - it should go to +9v to provide bias to the output transistors.

Also R8 is much too low a value - it needs to be approximately Hfe*R9. Maybe 100k.

The bias on the driver stage stage, Q3, is not well set - it will depend upon the Hfe of Q3.  Ideally with no signal the collector of Q3 should be at about half the rail voltage. 4.5V in this case. An emitter resistor and a resistor from base to ground can stabilize the operating point or even better is to have another stage with DC feedback.

The load is returned to the positive supply to provide what's called "Bootstrapping".  Without that the base current of Q5 would cause a voltage drop across R9 and limit the positive excursion.  The current into Q4 is provided by Q3 and is not so limited.

Here is an example Class B audio amplifier with those changes. This one uses diodes instead of the diode-connected transistors Q6 and Q7.

[image: Class B amplifier]